# Can we use checkSession method to renew the auh0 token?

Tags: angularjs, jwt, auth0

Can we use checkSession method to renew the auh0 token under the following circumstances?

1. We don't have a custom domain.
2. The user has blocked Third Party Cookies.

Is there any other solution to the above problem?
I am using Uniserval Login and I am able to sign in and sign up properly except unable to renew the token.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Universal Login flow, checkSession method should work to renew the token. It uses [silent authentication](https://auth0.com/docs/dashboard/guides/tenants/enable-sso-tenant) mechanism. Custom Domain is not necessary for Universal Login Flow.  I am not sure why it is failing. But few suggestion:

1. Check if you have configured [Seamless SSO](https://auth0.com/docs/dashboard/guides/tenants/enable-sso-tenant) correctly.
2. Monitor the browser network request and find out if there is any error message.
3. Check Auth0 dashboard logs. It should contain useful information why the silent authentications failed.

There are some common error message if the Silent authentication failed because session has expired. 
https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/silent-authentication#error-response

Comment: I checked network request and I found that when I allow 3rd Party Cookies setting then cookies are automatically getting attached to auth0 http request and checkSession succedes but If I disable it then checkSession fails because cookies are not attached to http request. I also checked SSO setting at the tenant level and it is fine.